# Scanner appears in device manager, but not scanners

Tags: windows-8, drivers, scanner

I've bought a scanner that claims to be compatible with the built in Windows Imaging components.

When plugging the scanner into a USB2 or 3 port (directly in the computer, not via a hub) the lights light up on the scanner and it appears in device manager as a "USB Scanner 5MP". However I'm then unable to acquire an image from it in Windows Fax & Scan, Paint.NET, any Office app or the built in Windows 8 Scanning 'Modern' app.

The scanner doesn't have any buttons on it that I can press. It's a [Veho VFS-002m](http://www.veho-world.com/main/shop_detail.aspx?article=60) and doesn't have any drivers on the CD that was bundled with it or the files that are downloadable from the website (as it claims it doesn't need drivers).

I've also tried using the scanner in Ubuntu 13.10. It appeared in dmesg when I connected it but the scanning software wouldn't pick it up there either.

Any suggestions on what else to try?

Comment: You'll have to try and eliminate the idea that the scanner is faulty: 1) try the scanner on another computer, 2) try a known-working scanner.

Comment: Scanner doesn't work on another Windows 8 computer. It does, however, work on the built in Windows XP tools on a third computer, haven't had chance to try a different scanner on the main two computers yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it show as USB Scanner 5MP but not under scanners it is just recognized as a camera - just as a webcam would be. There are document cameras out there, that claim to be scanners but they are just plain cameras.
On the link you provided it says: "captures an image in 1 second" This is another indication that it is just a plain camera und thus recognized as that. A real slide SCANNER also costs much more than 80 €.
A scan software expects a scanner to provide a WIA, TWAIN or ISIS interface, on Linux SANE. Since your "scanner" does not have any such driver bundled, it's not recoginzed by the scan software. 
If you use a video editing software that allows to acquire a picture directly from a camera, that software will most likely recognize your "scanner". The Media Impressions software mentioned on your link is most likely just such a video editing software in disguise. Just try whether Skype, for example, recognizes your "scanner" as a webcam - than you know for sure that it's just a camera.
So you need to use this "scanner" with video capture/editing software not with scan software. Windows Imaging components refers probably to such video software included in Windows.

Comment: I'd forgotten to come back to this question. It was indeed recognised as a webcam. I was able to boot into Linux in the end and use a capture program there to 'scan'